# How can I use a method of state class in any another state class of same Project?

Tags: flutter, flutter-state

I have a long method in a State class which I want to use in any other state class. So How can I do such that ?

Answer (score 0):

you can pass that method to the other class constructor. for example:

```
class ContainingMethod() {

MethodTaker(method)

method() {
...
}

}

// The class which method is passed to 

class MethodTaker {
final method;
MethodTaker(this.method)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to understand [state management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt).
By reading a little further into your question, I'd say you want to study and implement the `Provider` [package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider).